# How to transfer animation from one skeleton to another without erasing the animation that already exists on this skeleton?

Tags: animation

How can I transfer animation from one skeleton to another without erasing the animation that already exists on this skeleton?

If I use `Ctrl+L > Link Animation Data`, the animation is transferred, but the animation that was on the skeleton before disappears, and I need to combine both animations.

Comment: If you want to combine two different actions, you'll need to use the NLA editor to do so.  I'm not prepared to explain how to use NLA in a stack exchange post, but simply knowing what to search for may get you started.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan, this is helpful!